# Undefined method `street' for #<Profile:0x00007fea78589ac0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User who has a Profile (2 models). Here is the relevant part of my schema:

```
  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "about"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "street"
    t.integer "house_number"
    t.string "city"
    t.integer "zip_code"
    t.string "image"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

The reason I have a Profile as a separate model, as because I thought it was easier to assign roles later, for certain manipulations. So, now I am wondering, if it is possible to ask for

```
user.first_name , user.last_name, user.email and user.password
```

in the registration form and for

```
user.street, user.house_number, user.city and user.zip_code
```

in the Profile#new _form. Like this:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @profile], url: user_profiles_path, method: :post) do |form| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :about %>
    <%= form.text_area :about %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
    <% form.label "Profile photo" %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :street %><br />
    <%= form.text_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So here you can see, that avatar and about refer to a Profile, while street if from User table. But somehow this form, doesn't undertand this. I allow nested_attributes for :profile, but I guess, this doesn't matter for this form. I know, that maybe the easier way would be, to rearrange my table, so that all the adress attributes are stored in Profile. But as I am new to Rails and I really wish to learn more, I would love to know, if there is a way of saving to both @user and @profile in one form? Thank you!

Comment: I think in this case you can use `fields_for` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 0):

You're touching on two somewhat different concepts here that most beginners get stumped on.

The first is [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). A nested resource has its path nested under another resource.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
```

So now instead of `/ads` we have `/magazines/:magazine_id/ads`. So the routes themselves describe the relation between the two resources in a RESTful way - awesome.

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_magazine

  # GET /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/new
  def new
    @ad = @magazine.ads.new
  end

  # POST /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/new
  def create
    @ad = @magazine.ads.new(ad_params)
    if @ad.save
       redirect_to @ad
    else
       render :new
    end
  end

  def set_magazine 
    @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:magazine_id])
  end
  # ...
end
```

```
<%= form_for([@ad, @magazine]) do |f| >
  # ...
<% end %>
```

This will let you create ads that belong to a magazine. It will not magically let you create a magazine at the same time as an add in the same form.

That's where [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) comes in. It creates a super-powered setter in the model which lets it accept attributes for an associated model and creates / updates the associated records in the same request as the parent.

This for example would let us create a user and a profile in the same form:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end 

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f|>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :street, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  # ...
  <%= f.fields_for(:profile) do |profile_fields| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= profile_fields.label :about %>
      <%= profile_fields.text_area :about %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  # ...
<% end %>
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationRecord

  POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to :user
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user)
          .permit(:email, ..., profile_attributes: [:about])
  end
end
```

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` is one of the most misused, misunderstood and hardest concepts to grasp in rails though. If you're just starting out you should consider bypassing this and circling back around once you have a better understanding of rails.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sence to me. I did it the way you recommended and the form appeared on the page. However now the other links broke, this one returns an error:              <li><span class="bg-primary text-white rounded"><%= link_to 'My profile', user_profile_path(current_user.id, current_user.profile.id) %></span></li>

Error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"4"}, missing required keys: [:id]


But before it worked perfectly. So I guess, in this form I somehow need to pass profile.id. Am I right. And where would this be?

Comment: To start with you should make profile a [singular resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) as a user can only have one. Use `resource :profile` instead of `resources :profiles`. That will let you link to the profile with just `link_to user_profile_path(@user)` since it removes the id from the path.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean, I will need to correct every single path in views and controllers I have by now? Cause I also have a Reviews Controller, averything depends on this resources :profiles logic.

Comment: Yes. You should just be able to search and replace though.

Comment: Another question I have regarding this, is as there is only one profile, there is no index action in profiles controller. Right? So if I wish a user can go on a chosen profile, I will need to create an index page for users, right? And if a user clicks on another user, redirect to a profile. Am I thinking right? Since device didn't create a view for users, I will need to do it by hand and do smth. like @users = User.all. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah creating a `/users` page which displays an index of the users is one way to do it. Or you can create an un-nested `/profiles` route (plural since its the profiles of all the users) by using `resources :profiles, only: :index` outside of the `resources :users do ... end` block. It really depends on if there actually need to be a difference in listing/showing users vs listing/showing their profile.

Comment: And is there another way of doing it, cause I have to re-write everything from scratch. As a beginner, this kind of horryfies me. I have Profiles Controller, where a Profile Id is passed in every action. If don't have a Profile Id anymore, I don't even know, how to rewrite my profiles Controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203132/discussion-between-max-and-katharina-schreiber).